# Quote from Ramban, Shemos 6:2 -- where did Ramban hint?

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, shemot-exodus, va-eira, ramban

Ramban explains the various names of Hashem and levels of prophetic revelation (explaining pessukim 2-4 all in one comment). Right before the end of this section (paragraph 4 if using HaMeor layout) he writes: וכבר רמזתי פירוש "השמים  - where would this be? Back in Bereishis? I don't see any contextual reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to Breishit 1:8 according to sefaria.

https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.2?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en&p3=Genesis.1.8&ven3=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe3=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang3=en&aliyot3=0&w3=Ramban&lang4=en